# Graphics.RotateTransform() persists after Drawing the image

Tags: c#, .net, graphics

Writing a WinForms app that includes some Graphics. To rotate an image, I use the e.Graphics.RotateTransform(angle) method, then draw the image. A few lines later, I call e.Graphics.RotateTransform(0) so that no other images I have get rotated and should appear just normal. This is not the case however, and it seems that everything I draw afterwards is affected by the same Transforms. Why does RotateTransform(0) not reset the Transform for the page to be back to normal?

Note: this is an exert from the _Paint event in my code, but it's where the problem is happening. I've tried to include anything that may be relevant

```
e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(Chute1Rect.Width / 2 + Chute1Rect.X, Chute1Rect.Height / 2 + Chute1Rect.Y);

            if (increasing) //Chute is rotating out of the way
            {
                e.Graphics.RotateTransform(chuteAngle);

                e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(-1 * (Chute1Rect.Width / 2 + Chute1Rect.X), -1 * (Chute1Rect.Height / 2 + Chute1Rect.Y));
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(ChuteRotating, Chute1Rect);

                //These statements do not seem to be resetting the graphics drawing by the time we do the trains
                e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(Chute1Rect.Width / 2 + Chute1Rect.X, Chute1Rect.Height / 2 + Chute1Rect.Y);
                e.Graphics.RotateTransform(0);
            }
            else    //Chute is rotating into load position
            {
                if (chuteAngle == 0)    //Chute has rotated into load position
                {
                    e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(-1 * (Chute1Rect.Width / 2 + Chute1Rect.X), -1 * (Chute1Rect.Height / 2 + Chute1Rect.Y));

                    //Getting here means that the chute can be lifted & lowered because we are rotated down
                    if (lifting) //Chute is lifting out of the way
                    {
                        Chute1SlideRect.Y -= chuteDistance;
                        Chute2SlideRect.Y -= chuteDistance;

                        e.Graphics.DrawImage(ChuteSlide, Chute1SlideRect);
                        e.Graphics.DrawImage(ChuteSlide, Chute2SlideRect);
                    }
                    else    //Chute is lifting into load position
                    {
                        Chute1SlideRect.Y -= chuteDistance;
                        Chute2SlideRect.Y -= chuteDistance;

                        e.Graphics.DrawImage(ChuteSlide, Chute1SlideRect);
                        e.Graphics.DrawImage(ChuteSlide, Chute2SlideRect);
                    }

                    e.Graphics.DrawImage(ChuteJoint, Chute1JointRect);
                    e.Graphics.DrawImage(ChuteJoint, Chute2JointRect);
                }
                else
                {
                    e.Graphics.RotateTransform(chuteAngle);

                    e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(-1 * (Chute1Rect.Width / 2 + Chute1Rect.X), -1 * (Chute1Rect.Height / 2 + Chute1Rect.Y));
                    e.Graphics.DrawImage(ChuteRotating, Chute1Rect);

                    //These statements do not seem to be resetting the graphics drawing by the time we do the trains
                    e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(Chute1Rect.Width / 2 + Chute1Rect.X, Chute1Rect.Height / 2 + Chute1Rect.Y);
                    e.Graphics.RotateTransform(0);
                }
            }
//Down below here is where the trains get drawn
```

Comment: Either: rotate back by -oldAngle Or: ResetTransform OR Save&doyourstuff&Restore the Graphics object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out, so I thought I'd post my solution to maybe help someone else. I built 4 methods that take in parameters to keep it scalable in ratios, and had to call a method to basically reset the transformation grid before I drew anything after the rotation gets enacted. Here's the methods I made:

```
#region Methods for Transforms on Bunkers
    public void SetRotationTransformation(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.RotateTransform(chuteAngle);
    }

    public void InvertRotationTransformation(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e, int width, int X, int height, int Y)
    {
        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(width / 2 + X, height / 2 + Y);
        e.Graphics.RotateTransform(-chuteAngle);
        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(-1 * (width / 2 + X), -1 * (height / 2 + Y));
    }
    public void SetTranslateTransformation(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e, int width, int X, int height, int Y)
    {
        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(width / 2 + X, height / 2 + Y);
    }

    public void InvertTranslateTransformation(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e, int width, int X, int height, int Y)
    {
        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(-1 * (width / 2 + X), -1 * (height / 2 + Y));
    }
    #endregion
```

---

The Paint event where the drawing is happening:

```
 #region Draw Bunker
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(WeighBin, WeighBin1Rect);
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(WeighBin, WeighBin2Rect);

            e.Graphics.DrawImage(getLargeLoaderGraphic(chuteAngle), SurgeBin1Rect);
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(getLargeLoaderGraphic(chuteAngle), SurgeBin2Rect);
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(SurgeBinHat, SurgeBinHatRect);

            SetTranslateTransformation(e, Chute1Rect.Width, Chute1Rect.X, Chute1Rect.Height, Chute1Rect.Y);

            if (increasing) //Chute is rotating out of the way
            {
                SetRotationTransformation(e);
                InvertTranslateTransformation(e, Chute1Rect.Width, Chute1Rect.X, Chute1Rect.Height, Chute1Rect.Y);
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(ChuteRotating, Chute1Rect);
            }
            else    //Chute is rotating into load position
            {
                if (chuteAngle == 0)    //Chute has rotated into load position
                {
                    InvertTranslateTransformation(e, Chute1Rect.Width, Chute1Rect.X, Chute1Rect.Height, Chute1Rect.Y);

                    //Getting here means that the chute can be lifted & lowered because we are rotated down completely
                    if (lifting) //Chute is lifting out of the way
                    {
                        //Calculate Chute Slide position
                        Chute1SlideRect.Y -= chuteDistance;
                        Chute2SlideRect.Y -= chuteDistance;

                        e.Graphics.DrawImage(ChuteSlide, Chute1SlideRect);
                        e.Graphics.DrawImage(ChuteSlide, Chute2SlideRect);
                    }
                    else    //Chute is lifting into load position
                    {
                        //Calculate Chute Slide position
                        Chute1SlideRect.Y -= chuteDistance;
                        Chute2SlideRect.Y -= chuteDistance;

                        e.Graphics.DrawImage(ChuteSlide, Chute1SlideRect);
                        e.Graphics.DrawImage(ChuteSlide, Chute2SlideRect);

                        if (chuteDistance == 0)
                        {
                            if (opening) //Chute is in load position - start opening Gate
                            {
                                //Draw the Chute's Gate image second to keep it on top of the Chute's Slide
                                e.Graphics.DrawImage(ChuteSlideOpen, Chute1SlideOpenRect);
                                e.Graphics.DrawImage(ChuteSlideOpen, Chute2SlideOpenRect);

                                //Calculate Chute Gate position
                                Chute1GateRect.X += gateDistance;
                                Chute2GateRect.X += gateDistance;

                                e.Graphics.DrawImage(ChuteGate, Chute1GateRect);
                                e.Graphics.DrawImage(ChuteGate, Chute2GateRect);
                            }
                            else    //Begin closing Gate
                            {
                                //Draw the Chute's Gate image second to keep it on top of the Chute's Slide
                                e.Graphics.DrawImage(ChuteSlideOpen, Chute1SlideOpenRect);
                                e.Graphics.DrawImage(ChuteSlideOpen, Chute2SlideOpenRect);

                                //Calculate Chute Gate position
                                Chute1GateRect.X += gateDistance;
                                Chute2GateRect.X += gateDistance;

                                e.Graphics.DrawImage(ChuteGate, Chute1GateRect);
                                e.Graphics.DrawImage(ChuteGate, Chute2GateRect);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    //Draw the Chute's Joint graphics AFTER the Chute's Slide so it's on top
                    e.Graphics.DrawImage(ChuteJoint, Chute1JointRect);
                    e.Graphics.DrawImage(ChuteJoint, Chute2JointRect);
                }
                else
                {
                    SetRotationTransformation(e);
                    InvertTranslateTransformation(e, Chute1Rect.Width, Chute1Rect.X, Chute1Rect.Height, Chute1Rect.Y);

                    e.Graphics.DrawImage(ChuteRotating, Chute1Rect);
                }
            }
            #endregion

            #region Progress Bars
            //Position progress bar for bunker material levels  + (int)(ChuteHeight * 1.04)
            System1ProgressBar.Size = new Size(10, 45);
            System2ProgressBar.Size = new Size(10, 45);

            var progBar1X = -1 * Loader1Pos + (int)(ChuteWidth / 1.201);
            var progBar2X = Loader2Pos + (int)(ChuteWidth / 1.28);
            var progBarY = -1 * LoaderY - ChuteHeight / 21;


            System1ProgressBar.Location = new Point(progBar1X, progBarY);
            System2ProgressBar.Location = new Point(progBar2X, progBarY);

            System1ProgressBar.Maximum = 100;
            System1ProgressBar.Minimum = 0;
            System2ProgressBar.Maximum = 100;
            System2ProgressBar.Minimum = 0;

            if (!toppedOff)
            {
                if (System1ProgressBar.Value == System1ProgressBar.Maximum)
                {
                    toppedOff = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    System1ProgressBar.Increment(+2);
                    System2ProgressBar.Increment(+2);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(System1ProgressBar.Value == System1ProgressBar.Minimum)
                {
                    toppedOff = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    System1ProgressBar.Increment(-2);
                    System2ProgressBar.Increment(-2);
                }
            }
            #endregion

            InvertRotationTransformation(e, Chute1Rect.Width, Chute1Rect.X, Chute1Rect.Height, Chute1Rect.Y);

//NOW we can start drawing out trains and they don't flip everywhere - the above //method being called in this spot is what corrects that problem
```

Answer (score 2):

The [MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.rotatetransform%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) aren't explicit about this, but it appears that `RotateTransform` always modifies the existing transformation matrix, in which case `RotateTransform(0)` means "do nothing" rather than "set the rotation back to 0."  Try rotating it by the opposite of the initial angle.

Edit: or use `ResetTransform()` ([docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.resettransform%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) to get things back where you started and go from there.

Comment: I replaced my RotateTransforms with the ResetTransforms then put my TranslateTransforms after the Reset assuming it would put it back the way I had it setup before any Rotates were called (it's the same TranslateTransform I call at the beginning) - now the trains I draw afterwards aren't spinning, but they do disappear when the reset gets called, and the Translate follow the Reset does not look like it's actually kicking in. That Reset was nice to know about though!

Comment: disappearing when rotating and translating instead of rotating in place is a typical symptom of applying the rotation and translation in the wrong order. If you had a method called SetRotation and SetTranslation then not only would your original code have worked, but the order would not have mattered. But you have methods that apply transforms to the previous state, and order matters.

Comment: These methods you mention, you're suggesting that they do the actual call to the Transformation methods so that, in my Paint event, I just call my custom method that enacts the Transforms for me?